# Upload folder using Rackspace File Cloud

Tags: rackspace-cloud

I want to transfer a folder containing different types of file from my server to Rackspace File Cloud using Rackspace File Cloud API for PHP.

Can i transfer a folder to Rackspace File Cloud?
What is the corresponding php code for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Files API and documentation is located [here](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/files/api).

I believe that as Cloud Files is an object storage system, you'd create a Container to represent the folder, then transfer the individual files as Objects.